# Are there any instruments for DNS rewrite?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, rewrite

I have internal zone `old-internal-domain.local`. And we have records like `server1.old-internal-domain.local` and `www.server1.old-internal-domain.local`.

I want to make all records in `old-internal-domain.local` became accessible also in zone `new-internal-domain.company.tld` like `server1.new-internal-domain.company.tld` without copying records from old zone to new one.

I want something like *dns rewrite rules*, so when client queries server about `server1.new-internal-domain.company.tld`, server internally rewrites it into `server1.old-internal-domain.local` and resolves this. In response, it responds as `server1.new-internal-domain.company.tld A 10.20.30.40`

The key moment is to make it without creating copies of records.

It's better if I can use Windows DNS, but other software is OK too. Please advise.

- *This is not ActiveDirectory domain, just an ordinary DNS domain.*

Comment: At the DNS level your description is exactly what `DNAME` is about, but it might not really help you. And I have no idea if Windows DNS supports it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar use case using BIND.  In my scenario, an internal department name changed (and still does change frequently). But I didn't want to maintain old-dept-name and new-dept-name zone files.

So, on my master DNS server, my zone files are defined as:

```
        zone "old-dept.companyname.net" {
            type master;
            file "GEN/companyname.net";
            allow-query { GEN-CLIENTS; };
            allow-transfer { 
                    key "GEN-KEY";
            };
            // also-notify avoids problems about NS complaints
            also-notify {
                    10.x.x.x key GEN-KEY;
                    10.x.x.x key GEN-KEY;
            };
    };

    zone "new-dept.companyname.net" {
            type master;
            file "GEN/companyname.net";
            allow-query { GEN-CLIENTS; };
            allow-transfer { 
                    key "GEN-KEY";
            };
            also-notify {
                    10.x.x.x key GEN-KEY;
                    10.x.x.x key GEN-KEY;
            };
    };
```

Notice the same filename is used for both zones. NB: views are heavily used, which is what the GEN* stuff is about.

The key then is on the slave servers to not use the 'file' directive more than once - otherwise you'll run into locking problems during replication.  For such zones, the data only resides in RAM. It may not even be necessary to use it at all - it's been a while and I don't recall:

```
    zone "old-dept.companyname.net" {
            type slave;
            masters port 53 { 10.x.x.x key GEN-KEY; };
            file "GEN/companyname.net";
            allow-query { any; };
            notify no; 
    };

    zone "new-dept.companyname.net" {
            type slave;
            masters port 53 { 10.x.x.x key GEN-KEY; };
            // Notice there's no 'file' listed here - this prevents locking problems during replication
            allow-query { any; };
            notify no; 
    };
```

It's not a perfect solution, but I **can** have nearly unlimited "mirrors" of the same zone. The RAM-based zones are not a concern since they reload from the master at a slave server restart/reload or when a zone is updated.

Some drawbacks:

- You may (depending on how it's configured) get some sketchy warnings about NS records being out of zone.
- I'm using only static records - I have not tested using dynamic updates.
- You have to make a decision about reverse lookups. Do you want PTR records to point to old-dept? new-dept? the short name? all? Any option is easily possible, but it **IS** a consideration.

Good luck!